D3.js: getting "TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined" from my json dataset. I do not know why
I am trying to load my data onto a d3.js map but I keep getting this error: TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined
I am using my own json data and nothing is mapping. It seems that it cannot read the "yearninteenthirtyeight" object correctly. However, when I use this freecodecamp dataset and the "batchlorsOrHigher" object the data loads properly. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Here is my js code:
const colors = new Array("#e0f7ff","#b6e2ff","#87c4ff","#5d9eff","#007bff");

// -- GET FILES -- //
let gbCounts = "https://brycetreats-rsh.github.io/osu_greenbook_filehost/county_gb_counts_oneyear.json"
let countyGeoFile = "https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json"

let gbCountsData
let countyGeoData

// -- LOAD MAP -- //
let map = d3.select('#map')

let drawMap = () => {

    var colorScale = d3
        .scaleThreshold()
        .domain([0, 10, 30, 100, 220])
        .range(colors);


    map.selectAll('path')
        .data(countyGeoData.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', d3.geoPath())
        .attr("stroke", "#333")
        .attr('class', 'county')
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => { //d is a county data item
            //get ID of current data element
            let currentID = d.id;
            // console.log(i, currentID)
            //find education that matches id
            let county = gbCountsData.find((item) => {
                if (item.fips === currentID) {
                    // console.log(item.state)
                    return item;
                } 
            })
            
            return colorScale(county.yearninteenthirtyeight);
        })
}

// -- LOAD MAP DATA -- //
d3.json(gbCounts).then(
    (data, error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            // if no error, load data
            gbCountsData = data;
            console.log(gbCountsData)

            // load map after data is loaded
            d3.json(countyGeoFile).then(
                (data, error) => {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        // if no error, load data
                        countyGeoData = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties);
                        drawMap()

                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
)

I'll add my html as well JIC
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>OSU Green Book SVG Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="timeseriesmap.css" />
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.min.js"></script> -->
        <style>
            /* Nothing here so far */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1 class="siderbar-title">The Green Book</h1>
                        <p class="sidebar-text">Body Text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sliderContainer">
                        <div id="slider"></div>
                        <div class="year start-year">1938</div>
                        <div class="year end-year">1963</div>
                        <div class="zoom-button"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="map-container">
                    <div id="map-tooltip"></div>
                    <div class="map-key"></div>
                    <svg id="map"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script defer src="timeseriesmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>

I've tried modifying my dataset various different times but nothing seems to work.

county_gb_counts_oneyear.json does not contain a "fips" of 9015, so in this line (of that iteration) return colorScale(county.yearninteenthirtyeight) county is undefined.

I went through and added the fips code and I am still receiving the same issue. Matching the number of counties to the number of fips codes does not seem to be the solution.

Now you are missing "fips" 9011.  This is pretty simple debugging.  I just put a console.log(currentID) after let currentID = d.id; in your fill to see which ID is causing the error.
